# Why can't add free ClearDB MySQL to my app on heroku?

Tags: database, heroku

I got this error
Item could not be created:
Please verify your account to install this add-on plan (please enter a credit card) For more information, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify

Is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same situation, but don't worry about it.
This verification step is just in order to make sure that you can afford to pay the expenses afterwards.

Even if you select a free plan, you still have to bind the credit card for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).